# What are the scalability benefits of splinting monolithic codebase into microservices?

Tags: microservices, scalability

Let's say that facebook runs as a single binary. Publishing N copies of this service in N servers split the workload evenly, fine. Now, if I split facebook codebase in half, exactly how it is more scalable? (in the sense of y-axis scale from this [article](https://akfpartners.com/growth-blog/scale-cube)).

If I allocate 1 server for first half and 2 servers for second half, it will certainly be faster than one monolithic server, because now we have 3. Thats exactly like [x-axis](https://akfpartners.com/growth-blog/scale-cube) scaling. Only that now you have uneven load-balancing.

But consider the servers to be 25% of its original size. Right from the startup, these servers have a higher percentage of used RAM. This is so because splitting code in half doesn't implies halving RAM footprint. Each server will be wasting more RAM on duplicated library code, etc.

I wonder if there is any benefit on using microservice from this performance/computing resource perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microservices architecture allows developers to create separate components of an application through building an application from a combination of small services...

Now... If we had a monolith application, and identify that one specific feature recive more trafic/request than other then we need to scale all application, including the parts of application with lower or zero trafic, and if this part of application crash, than all application crashes! In microservices architecture every small feature could be deployed as a small microservices, in this scenarios we can scale only the part of system that we need, and even if this service crash, all other parts of system still alive... This scenario show us two benefits: isolation and scalability.

When you think in RAM consumption, you need to take the scenario above in consideration, because we can spaw a service only when we need, and if we does not need we can reduce to a lower number of instances and here we can obtain gains in terms of performance/computing efeciency resource perspective... Looking in term of storage and still tink in footprint, a monolith application mybe use some libs to a specific group of features and another group of feature maybe use other libs... here the problem remain! Mey we had in a monolith application scalling a lot os libs and resources being scaled that we does not need to scale.

If we think in life cycle of a aplication, develop new features can be achieved developping or updating small services so, functionality associated with microservice architecture is the ability to easily understand when compared to an entire monolithic app. The microservice approach lets developers choose the right tools for the right task. They can build each server utilizing a language or framework they need without affecting the communication between other microservices.  This scenarios show us more two benefits: Productivity and flexibility.